# Unprotect an Excel file programmatically

Tags: python, excel, com, pywin32

We're getting an Excel file from a client that has open protection and Write Reserve protection turned on.  I want to remove the protection so I can open the Excel file with the python xlrd module.  I've installed the pywin32 package to access the Excel file through COM, and I can open it with my program supplying the two passwords, save, and close the file with no errors.  I'm using Unprotect commands as described in MSDN network, and they're not failing, but they're also not removing the protection.  The saved file still requires two passwords to open it after my program is done.  Here's what I have so far:

```
import os, sys
impdir = "\\\\xxx.x.xx.x\\allshare\\IT\\NewBusiness\\Python_Dev\\import\\"
sys.path.append(impdir)
from UsefulFunctions import *
import win32com.client

wkgdir = pjoin(nbShare, 'NorthLake\\_testing')
filename = getFilename(wkgdir, '*Collections*.xls*')
xcl = win32com.client.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
xcl.visible = True
pw_str = raw_input("Enter password: ")
try:
    wb = xcl.workbooks.open(filename, 0, False, None, pw_str, pw_str)
except Exception as e:
    print "Error:", str(e)
    sys.exit()
wb.Unprotect(pw_str)
wb.UnprotectSharing(pw_str)
wb.Save()
xcl.Quit()
```

Can anyone provide me the correct syntax for unprotect commands that will work?

Comment: Figured out how to edit question and add tags; still need help with main question.

Comment: I think you can use `SaveAs` and pass empty strings to the `Password` and `WriteResPassword` parameters  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841185(v=office.15).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suggestion from @Tim Williams worked.  (Use SaveAs and pass empty strings for the Password and WriteResPassword parameters.)  I used 'None' for the 'format' parameter after filename, and I used a new filename to keep Excel from prompting me asking if OK to overwrite the existing file.  I also found that I did not need the wb.Unprotect and wb.UnprotectSharing calls using this approach.

Comment: If you use `xcl.DisplayAlerts = False` before saving then it should let you overwrite the original without a prompt.

Answer (score 17):

This function works for me

```
def Remove_password_xlsx(filename, pw_str):
    xcl = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
    wb = xcl.Workbooks.Open(filename, False, False, None, pw_str)
    xcl.DisplayAlerts = False
    wb.SaveAs(filename, None, '', '')
    xcl.Quit()
```

Comment: This is the only one that works for me and I have virtually tried all the other suggested solutions. Unprotects the file and pandas can then parse it. Excellent

Comment: Super useful. Thanks!

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.

Comment: only works on windows due to using win32com :(

Comment: It might be advisable to toggle DisplayAlerts back to True after saving. Also, there could be other workbooks that are opened, and quitting Excel could result in lost changes. Recommend to close the workbook, then check the number of workbooks and if there are no more workbooks, then quit the application. After the wb.SaveAs(), use: `xcl.DisplayAlerts=True; wb.Close(); if not len(xcl.Workbooks): xcl.Quit()`

Answer (score 8):

This post helped me a lot. I thought I would post what I used for my solution in case it may help someone else. Just Unprotect, DisaplyAlerts=False, and Save. Made it easy for me and the file is overwritten with a usable unprotected file.

```
import os, sys
import win32com.client

def unprotect_xlsx(filename):
    xcl = win32com.client.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
    pw_str = '12345'
    wb = xcl.workbooks.open(filename)
    wb.Unprotect(pw_str)
    wb.UnprotectSharing(pw_str)
    xcl.DisplayAlerts = False
    wb.Save()
    xcl.Quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    filename = 'test.xlsx'
    unprotect_xlsx(filename)
```

Answer (score 6):

you can unprotect excel file sheets with python openpyxl module without knowing the password:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
sample = load_workbook(filename="sample.xlsx")
for sheet in sample: sheet.protection.disable()
sample.save(filename="sample.xlsx")
sample.close()
```

where parameter "filename" is the path of your excel file which in here i have used local dir path.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Error: "zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file"

Comment: This is for unprotecting sheets, not the workbook itself.

Answer (score 2):

if you are on MacOS (or maybe Linux? not tested)

You have to install `Microsoft Excel` and `xlwings`

`pip install xlwings`

Then run this:

```
import pandas as pd
import xlwings as xw

def _process(filename):
  wb = xw.Book(filename)
  sheet = wb.sheets[0]
  df = sheet.used_range.options(pd.DataFrame, index=False, header=True).value
  wb.close()
  return df
```

Resources:

- Adapted from this script:
  https://davidhamann.de/2018/02/21/read-password-protected-excel-files-into-pandas-dataframe/
- xlwings documentation: https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/api.html

Comment: it's don’t work for me, did you succeed with this code ?

Comment: This isnt a solution to the question. Nothing in your code is dealing with the password. This will just open the excel file which then asks you for the password, might as well do it manually

Answer (score 0):

The solution that just worked for me on mac was https://github.com/nolze/msoffcrypto-tool. It even has a CLI!

```bash
python -m pip install msoffcrypto-tool
msoffcrypto-tool encrypted.xlsx decrypted.xlsx -p PaSsWoRd
```

but there is a python API too if you need to do something more complicated.