# Pandas unable to open this Excel file

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to use python pandas to open an Excel file. Code is simple as shown below;

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('../TestXLWings.xlsm', sheetname="TestSheet")
```

I got an error below;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.2\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1599, in <module>
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.2\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1026, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.2\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Users/testing/Dropbox/Test-XLwings/test.py", line 3, in <module>
    df = pd.read_excel('../TestXLWings.xlsm', sheetname="TestSheet")
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py", line 203, in read_excel
    io = ExcelFile(io, engine=engine)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py", line 260, in __init__
    self.book = xlrd.open_workbook(io)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlrd\__init__.py", line 441, in open_workbook
    ragged_rows=ragged_rows,
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlrd\book.py", line 87, in open_workbook_xls
    ragged_rows=ragged_rows,
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlrd\book.py", line 595, in biff2_8_load
    raise XLRDError("Can't find workbook in OLE2 compound document")
xlrd.biffh.XLRDError: Can't find workbook in OLE2 compound document
```

My Excel file is xlsm and protected by password. What does OLE2 compound document mean exactly? Does pandas have problems opening this kind of Excel files? I am using python v3.6

Comment: I am using xlrd 1.0.0. This is the latest version. I just did a `conda update`

Comment: I had a similar problem with protected files before. Are there any protection/locks on the file?

Comment: @ayhan, the Excel file is protected with password.

Comment: I removed the protection on the files using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28414136/2285236) and read the files: there were no other solutions that I could find. It only works on windows though.

Comment: Thanks. I guess you have got the answer. Protection has to be removed from Excel in order for xlrd to work. I just discovered another way to open protected Excel files. xlwings is able to read protected Excel files. I think xlwings is the way to go for me.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I will answer my own question. In one of the comments from ayhan, Excel-protected files cannot be read by xlrd. One solution is to remove the protection.

[I need the command to unprotect an Excel file from python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27556751/i-need-the-command-to-unprotect-an-excel-file-from-python/28414136#28414136)

Another solution to read the Excel-protected file is to use xlwings. I have verified that xlwings is able to read protected Excel files when the Excel file is opened.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a new excel file and remove sensitivity label in excel. Then be able to read the file with pd.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).