# Collecting Sheet Names from a Folder of Excel Workbooks

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl, glob

I have a folder of numerous .xslx files on my desktop and I am trying to iterate through them one by one to collect the respective sheet names automatically from each workbook.

```
import openpyxl
import glob


# specifying the path to csv files

path = "C:/Users/X/Desktop/Test"
  
# csv files in the path

files = glob.glob(path + "/*.xlsx")

sheet_names = []

for x in files:
    openpyxl.load_workbook(files)
    sheet_names.append(files.sheetnames)
```

I am getting an error code:

```
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list
```

Is there any way to do this iteratively versus one by one if I have all of the workbook names in a list?

Thank you.

I am looking for the sheet names in each respective Excel workbook file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
sheet_names = []

for x in files:
    sheet_names.append(openpyxl.load_workbook(x).sheetnames)
```

Or, using a [`list comprehension`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```py
sheet_names = [openpyxl.load_workbook(x).sheetnames for x in files]
```

---

**Update**:

If you encounter an error message like:

```py
BadZipFile: File is not a zip file
```

This probably means that the file you are trying to access is corrupted. I.e. `openpyxl` is simply unable to open the file, and the remedy to this situation, i.e. *fixing the file, I mean*, lies outside the code; you will have to take a closer look at that particular file.

However, you can use `try ... except` to avoid having such an event interrupt the rest of your procedure. E.g.:

```py
sheet_names = []

for x in files:
    try:
        sheet_names.append(openpyxl.load_workbook(x).sheetnames)
    except Exception as e:
            print(f'Unable to process {x}. Error raised', end=' ')
            print(e)
```

E.g. whenever the code encounters a `BadZipFile`, now you'll see a print: `Unable to process {path_to/some_file.xlsx}. Error raised File is not a zip file`.

---

**Explanation error**

The error occurs because you are referencing `files` (i.e. a `list`), rather than the items inside the list (i.e. `x`) in this line:

```py
    openpyxl.load_workbook(files) # we need `x` here instead of `files`
```

Next, in order to actually use the result from the function call, you should have assigned it to a variable, e.g. `wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(x)` and then pass it to the `list.append` function. I.e.:

```py
    sheet_names.append(files.sheetnames) # we would need `wb.sheetnames` here
```

However, as shown above, you can just put all of this is a one-liner (so, skipping the intermediate assignment to `wb`).

Comment: Thank you for the assistance. I am getting an error where my files do not have the full path appended. I would need to tack on "C:/Users/X/Desktop/" to every string element in the list for this to function. Thank you a million.

Comment: Do you mean that your list `files` contains entries without the preceding `path` (i.e. `"C:/Users/X/Desktop/Test"`)? That would seem very curious to me giving your code.

Comment: I had the names of the Excel files in my list *files*, but now I have appended the full path to the beginning of each element x in *files*, that is all cleaned up. Now, the issue I am having is: "error code: BadZipFile: File is not a zip file" for the code provided.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Updated the answer to handle the error in question (and potential others).

Answer (score 0):

See: [Pandas: Looking up the list of sheets in an excel file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17977540/pandas-looking-up-the-list-of-sheets-in-an-excel-file):

```
import pandas as pd
import os

excelfolder = r'/home/bera/Downloads/'

for root, folder, files in os.walk(excelfolder):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.xlsx'):
            print(file)
            fullname = os.path.join(root, file)
            print(pd.ExcelFile(fullname).sheet_names)
            
            #Excelfile123.xlsx
            #['Sheet1', 'Sheet2', 'Sheet3']
            
            #excelfile2.xlsx
            #['A', 'B']
```

Comment: This functioned perfectly for some time, I collected about 50 excel file names with their respective sheet names. I have over 200+ excel files in this folder, is there a limit to the number of excel files? I got this error message: "XLRDError: Can't find workbook in OLE2 compound document".

Comment: I dont know if there's a limit. I just tried it on a folder with two files in it. Can it be this problem?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45725645/pandas-unable-to-open-this-excel-file

Comment: Hey, I located the two files that were giving issues. I will test the protections and another article I saw mentioned that there was a version issue too. Thanks for teaching me this code, I will be using it quite a bit. I was able to extract the rest of the files and create a dictionary with filename:sheetnames being the key:value pairs.