# Error trying to read blockede xls file on python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xls

I am trying to open an Xls file on using python pandas ( also tried several others libraries like xlrd and pyexcel)  and wasnt able to open it. 
when a try to used the comand

```
df = pd.read_excel('mil.xls')
```

I get following error:

> _locate_stream(Workbook): seen
>       0  5 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4     20  4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 3     40  2

I found out that when, before trying to read it, I unblock the file, that is, disable manually the protected view mode on excel, I could read the file normally. 
Is there a way I can unblock the .Xls file on python though some librarie ?

Comment: are you still using xlrd?

Comment: I tried to read the file with xlrd library but I got the same error.

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27556751/i-need-the-command-to-unprotect-an-excel-file-from-python

Comment: My file doesnt have a passoword.. I think it is something related to enconding or the excel version in which the file as save. If I open the file on excel and save it, and  then try to open it, the I am able to do it. But I need to open the file straight from the url, therefore this procedure it isnt possible

Answer (score 1):

I've noted that if you open and save the file you can read it. This piece of code solve the problem:

```
xcl = win32com.client.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
wb = xcl.workbooks.open(filename)
xcl.DisplayAlerts = False
wb.Save()
xcl.Quit()
```