# error trying to read .xls file on python using pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xls, pyexcel

I am trying to open an Xls file on using python pandas ( also tried several others libraries like xlrd and pyexcel) but wasnt able to open it. When a try to use the comand:

```
df = pd.read_excel('serie.xls')
```

I get following error:

> _locate_stream(Workbook): seen 0 5 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 20 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 3 40 2
>
> CompDocError: Workbook corruption: seen[3] == 4

I found out that the file was in "protected view mode". Then, when I disabled manually the protected view mode on excel, I could read the file normally. Is there a way I can unprotect the .Xls file on python  ?

Comment: possible dupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47283342/error-trying-to-read-blockede-xls-file-on-python

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error trying to read blockede xls file on python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47283342/error-trying-to-read-blockede-xls-file-on-python)