# Python Script to automate refreshing an excel spreadsheet without asking for password

Tags: python, excel, vba, ssas

I would like to automatically refresh my excel file which is connected to Analysis service without asking me to enter password each time i run the code or a way to pass the password without manual entry.

Currently the code which M using is

```
import win32com.client
import pandas as pd
# Start an instance of Excel
xlapp = win32com.client.DispatchEx("Excel.Application")

# Open the workbook in said instance of Excel
wb = xlapp.workbooks.open(r"<excel path>")

# Optional, e.g. if you want to debug
# xlapp.Visible = True

# Refresh all data connections.
wb.RefreshAll()
wb.Save()

file_name =  'sample.xlsx'
sheet =  'Sheet1'
df = pd.read_excel(io=file_name, sheet_name=sheet)
print(df.head(50))  


# Quit
xlapp.Quit()
```

How to automatically refresh the Excel file without asking me password or an alternative to send the password.

Thanks for you answer!

Comment: You will need to [unprotect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27556751/unprotect-an-excel-file-programmatically)

Comment: I cannot do that, instead is there a way I pass my password in the code itself without prompting to enter the password?

Comment: Yes, unprotect as seen in that link, disable alerts and then reprotect.

Comment: Yes this works when your file has a password, but i have to enter password for my external data source connection when i run the code. I need to bypass it in the code. Can it be done?