# Make excel file(.xlsx) unprotected in mac

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, xlsx, pywin32

I am trying to unprotect an excel file using python. I have the password with me.
I want to extract it so that I can access the internal .XML files.
I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27556751/unprotect-an-excel-file-programmatically) but I am unsuccessful in extracting the data.

Comment: What do you mean by "unsuccessful"? Any errors? Unexpected output?

Comment: So the thing is win32com is available for windows only and I need some module/library that works with Linux environment.

Answer (score 0):

For mac, I used https://github.com/nolze/msoffcrypto-tool module and it is working fine for .xlsx files.

```
import msoffcrypto
import io

with open("encrypted.xlsx", "rb") as f:
    file = msoffcrypto.OfficeFile(f)
    file.load_key(password="password")  # Use password

    with open("decrypted.xlsx", "wb") as f1:
        file.decrypt(f1)
```

Comment: This worked for me great! But they even have a CLI, so all I had to do was `python -m pip install msoffcrypto-tool &&
msoffcrypto-tool encrypted.xlsx decrypted.xlsx -p PaSsWoRd`!